# Kafka - Spark Streaming Integration: DStreams and Task reuse

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka, dstream

I am trying to understand the internals of Spark Streaming (not Structured Streaming), specifically the way tasks see the DStream. I am going over the source code of Spark in scala, [here](https://github.com/apache/spark). I understand the call stack:

```
ExecutorCoarseGrainedBackend (main) -> Executor (launchtask) -> TaskRunner (Runnable).run() -> task.run(...)
```

I understand the DStream really is a hashmap of RDDs but I am trying to understand the way tasks see the DStream. I know that there are basically 2 approaches to Kafka Spark integration:

- ***Receiver* based using High Level Kafka Consumer APIs**

  Here a new (micro-)batch is created  at every batch interval (say 5 secs) with say 5 partitions (=> 1 sec block interval) by the *Receiver* task and handed downstream to *Regular* tasks.

  **Question:** Considering our example where every microbatch is created every 5 secs; has exactly 5 partitions and all these partitions of all the microbatches are supposed to be DAG-ged downstream the exact same way, is the same *regular* task re-used over and over again for the same partition id of every microbatch (RDD) as a long running task? e.g.

  If *ubatch1* of partitions *(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5)* at time *T0* is assigned to task ids *(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)*, will *ubatch2* of partitions *(P1',P2',P3',P4',P5')* at time *T5* be also assigned to the same set of tasks *(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)* or will new tasks *(T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)* be created for *ubatch2*?

  If the latter is the case then, wouldn't it be performance intensive having to send new tasks over the network to executors every 5 seconds when you already know that there are tasks doing the exact same thing and could be re-used as long running tasks?
- ***Direct* using Low Level Kafka Consumer APIs**

  Here a Kafka Partition maps to a Spark Partition and therefore a Task. Again, considering 5 Kafka partitions for a topic ***t***, we get 5 Spark partitions and their corresponding tasks.

  **Question:** Say, the *ubatch1* at *T0* has partitions *(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5)* assigned to tasks *(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5).* Will *ubatch2* of partitions *(P1',P2',P3',P4',P5')* at time *T5* be also assigned to the same set of tasks *(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)* or will new tasks *(T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)* be created for *ubatch2*?

Comment: That, I agree. I am trying to get an insight into this to be able to understand the entire picture bottom up. I want to write one myself.. A simplistic one.. It will help me understand lots of aspects

Comment: Very noble, a bit like myself, but there is also Structured Streaming which is not there entirely makes life a lot easier. there is only so many hours in a day!

Comment: Anyone who could help me understand this? There is no problem moving from Receiver to Direct based approach or even to Structured Streaming for that matter. Just that I am trying to understand the inner details of each to be able to better appreciate the evolution time line, the existing problem and the approach taken.

Answer (score 0):

After going over the source code of Apache Spark, here is the definitive answer:

Its a pretty intuitive approach.

1. We use the *SparkStreamingContext (ssc)* from the *SparkContext* to create and save our sequence of transformations on the stream in the form of a DStream DAG ending at a *ForEachDStream* DStream where each DStream is a container of RDDs i.e. Hashmap
2. The *ForEachDStream* is registered with the DStreamGraph of the *ssc*.
3. On *ssc.start*(-ing) the execution, the JobScheduler puts our saved plan on an event loop, that executes every *ubatch interval secs* creating/extracting an RDD for each DStream and from each DStream at that time, and saving it in the HashMap for the corr. DStream for a *rememberDuration* duration of time (e.g. for windowing)
4. and in the process creates the RDD DAG ending in the action specified in the *ForEachDStream* which then submits a new job to the DAG Scheduler.

This cycle repeats every ubatch interval seconds.